# Exception: Exception caught in workbook destructor. Explicit close() may be required for workbook.python

Tags: python, excel

I wrote a program using the pandas library. I am trying to write into an excel file and i wrote this code:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(DIR_PATH + 'output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

styled.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

styled2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2', index=False)
print(styled2)
styled3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet3', index=False)
print(styled3)
writer.save()
writer.close()
excel.Application.Quit()

################ setting column width to fit data ##################
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(DIR_PATH + 'output.xlsx')
ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
wb.Save()
ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
wb.Save()
ws3 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet3")
wb.Save()
ws1.Columns.AutoFit()
ws2.Columns.AutoFit()
ws3.Columns.AutoFit()
wb.Save()
wb.close()
excel.Application.Quit()
```

I got the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "K:/test_results.efrat.py", line 151, in <module>
    styled.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
  File "K:\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style.py", line 175, in to_excel
    engine=engine)
  File "K:\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 652, in write
    freeze_panes=freeze_panes)
  File "K:\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 1750, in write_cells
    for cell in cells:
  File "K:\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 617, in get_formatted_cells
    self._format_body()):
  File "K:\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 529, in _format_regular_rows
    for cell in self._generate_body(coloffset):
  File "K:\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 601, in _generate_body
    styles = self.styler._compute().ctx
  File "K:\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style.py", line 514, in _compute
    r = func(self)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "K:\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style.py", line 604, in _applymap
    result = self.data.loc[subset].applymap(func)
  File "K:\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1472, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "K:\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 890, in _getitem_tuple
    retval = getattr(retval, self.name)._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
  File "K:\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1901, in _getitem_axis
    return self._getitem_iterable(key, axis=axis)
  File "K:\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1143, in _getitem_iterable
    self._validate_read_indexer(key, indexer, axis)
  File "K:\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1206, in _validate_read_indexer
    key=key, axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
KeyError: "None of [['Failed/Passed']] are in the [columns]"
Exception ignored in: <bound method Workbook.__del__ of <xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook object at 0x00000000176730F0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "K:\venv\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 154, in __del__
Exception: Exception caught in workbook destructor. Explicit close() may be required for workbook.
```

But i used `wb.close()` at the end of the code so i dont understand why i got this exception. Does anyone know what the problem is and h ow can i solve it? Thanks.

Comment: The XlsxWriter exception isn't the exception that is causing the issue, it is just being caught in it's destructor. This exception isn't in newer versions. The exception you need to look at and fix is the previous KeyError one from Pandas.